# Relationship between PCA and KPCA

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, kernel-trick

The relation between PCA and KPCA seems somewhat confusing. Basically, the Kernel variant of PCA can be described as constructing the normalized kernel matrix of the data $n \times n$ (n is the number of samples), followed by eigendecomposition to extract the linear principal components. Then, KPCA can extract up to n (number of samples) nonlinear principal components.

Does this have the same effect as performing PCA on the data matrix associated with a kernel matrix, where the data matrix $X$ of kernel matrix $K$ is expressed as:
$$
K = U\Sigma U^{\top} = U\Sigma^{1/2}(U\Sigma^{1/2})^{\top} = XX^{\top}
$$

In other words, for $K = XX^{\top}$, the following relation should hold between PCA and KPCA:
$$
KPCA(K) == PCA(X^{\top})
$$

Does the above relation hold?

Comment: Yes, but note that $X$ is often infinite-dimensional and cannot be explicitly constructed, let alone analyzed. That's the essence of "kernel trick": instead of $X$, we work with $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A great reference is the original paper: 
[Nonlinear Component Analysis as an Eigenvalue Problem - Scholkopf, et. al.](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/Kernel/kernelPCA_scholkopf.pdf)

The idea is that you are boosting your vectors $x_i$ to a higher dimensional space via $\Phi(x_i)$.This gives you a covariance matrix $\bar{C}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\Phi(x_i)\Phi(x_i)^T,$ which has corresponding eigenvectors $\bar{C}V_k=\lambda_kV_k$. You now define $K(x,y):=\Phi(x)\cdot \Phi(y)$ and $K_{ij}:=K(x_i,x_j)$, so that by the rules of linear algebra, the PCA projection for $x$ looks like:

$$V^k\cdot\Phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^kK(x_i,x),$$

where $a_i^k$ can be determined by computing the eigenvalues of $K_{ij}$. Specifically the $a_{i}^k$ are determined through requiring that $V^k=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^k\Phi(x_i)$ and $V^k\cdot V^k=1$, where the first equation restates the classical fact that the span of eigenvectors is equivalent to the span of the row/column vectors of a square positive definite matrix. Equivalently, $a^k$ are eigenvectors of the kernel matrix $K_{ij}$:   $Ka^k=n\lambda \alpha^k$.